# Enter field value in different languages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, globalize3, globalize

I'm writing an application that will be accessed by users of different languages.
As I understand, the standard way to localize Rails app is to use gems `i18n` (localize static text) and `globalize` (localize db field values). These gems work fine and let me display fields in different languages on a same view using `Globalize.with_locale(...) { ... }`.

However, what I need to do is to **input** values in different languages on a same view. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

More specifically - I need to have a number of `<inputs>` inside `<form>` which (after the form is submitted) save their values into different locales.

```
                   ____________________________
Description (en): |             Ruby           |
                  |____________________________|

                   ____________________________
Description (de): |             Rubin          |
                  |____________________________|
```

etc

Comment: What do you mean with "save their values into different locales"? Create separate records in a database with a column indicating which locale this is for?

Comment: I mean that user enters field values in different languages and these values can be used afterward. `globalize` creates a separate table to store field values in different languages (e.g. `posts_tranlsations`). If this cannot be done with `globalize` then another gem will be fine

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is change the **label** of the input, this is easily solved like so:

```
=form.label :model_attribute, t('translation.in.your.locale.file')
```

Comment: you've missed the point of the question. He's trying to (for example) submit an English and a Spanish value for the same field.